# Which packages do I need to include to simulate MathJax?

Tags: packages, amsmath, mathjax

I've been using [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) for a while, and I am comfortable with formatting math in MathJax. Now I am trying to write my first real LaTeX document on "ShareLaTeX". However, I am having trouble, because some things which format on Math.SE (such as `\tag {1}`) are not compiling with my current packages. I've looked through sample math documents, and what I have so far is:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

What are the packages I need to be able to fully emulate what I can do on Math.SE? Alternatively, is there a way for me to format math on Math.SE and download it into a nice PDF?

Comment: It is the other way around, mathjax emulates TeX syntax. `\tag` works pretty OK but we need to see your code. Mathjax is a limited TeX environment if it has something TeX surely has it way more comprehensively.

Comment: @percusse Sorry if I wasn't clear, I understand that MathJax is the one which emulates LaTex. But without any packages I can't format almost any math, so I would like to know the minimum packages that I need in order to be able to transfer all the stuff I wrote on MathJax to LaTex.

Comment: @percusse I am using all the packages listed in the question and \tag {1} is not compiling

Comment: \tag is for forced reference for equations. You just use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` and it will give you the tag automatically. If you also use `\label{myeq}` then you can refer to it via `\eqref{myeq}` in the text if you load `amsmath`

Comment: It's hard to help you if we don't know what you are doing so if your question has not already been answered in the comments can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: `\tag` is defined in `amsmath` so if you are getting an error you have used it incorrectly, but as you have not shown how you used it and not shown the error that you got, it's not possible to help! In general the mathjax documentation for its latex support lists in each case which latex package is being emulated. see the right hand column of http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\tag` is defined in `amsmath` so is defined if you have

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

In general the mathjax documentation for its latex support lists in each case which latex package is being emulated. see the right hand column of

https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/index.html